# Why measures are disappearing from my PBI report?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, powerbi, sql-server-2019, ssas-tabular

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 to import data from a DWH data source built on SQL Server 2019. This data is to be used to populate a report in PowerBI services, but when I try to create a measure `Mnt%` in my cube on Visual Studio, it doesn't appear in my tables in PowerBI.

I created a measurement `Mnt%` from two existing measurements (which appear in the measurement tables in VS and PowerBI). The measurement `Mnt%` only appears in the measurement section in VS, but not in PowerBI report. Also, the measure disappears from the table where I created it a few hours later. I don't understand why.

Comment: It seems like a bug check this link https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Issues/Power-BI-Desktop-intermittent-bug-measures-disappearing/idi-p/1595781

Comment: Thanks. On my tabular model in Visual Studio, the measure appeared but it was not displayed on Power BI. I was unable to save the measure in the tabular model and deploy it.